# Plotting two dependent function with respect to each other

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, parameters, interpolation

I am writing a small code in Matlab to achieve following:

X, Y, and Z are all vectors and correspond to different physical quantities.

x1 and x2 are two different vectors made from allowed values which X can have.

Now I have Y as function of x1

Y=f(x1)

and Z as function of x2

Z=g(x2)

I do not know the functions 'f' and 'g' explicitly but I have a table which gives me Y and Z corresponding to x1 and x2 respectively.

So I can plot Y=f(x1) and Z = g(x2) in MATLAB using plotyy function using a common x-scale but 2 different y axis.

I want to plot Y as function of Z. What will be the most efficient way to do this? I guess I might need to use interpolation somewhere in this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yes, interpolation seems like an appropriate method. See [`interp1`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @mikkola, interpolation would be the way to go. You could interpolate Y onto the domain of Z, Z onto the domain of Y, or Y and Z onto a completely different domain. Do be careful though, as you want to make sure you interpolate, not extrapolate. The default for `interp1` is linear interpolation, but you can get it to implement other types of interpolation by passing in an optional parameter.

The following is an example with two different domains `x1` and `x2`, corresponding to functions `Y=sin(x)` and `Z=cos(x)`. These are interpolated onto a different domain `x3` so that `Y` and `Z` can be plotted against each other, yielding a circle as we would expect.

```
% Two different domains
x1 = 0:0.02:2*pi;
x2 = 0:0.03:2*pi;

% Yielding two different functions
Y = sin(x1);
Z = cos(x2);

% Interpolate them both onto a common domain (x3)
x3 = 0:0.01:2*pi;
Yi = interp1(x1,Y,x3);
Zi = interp1(x2,Z,x3);

% Plot - circle, as expected
figure;
plot(Yi,Zi)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will try that !